# maximum recursion error in custom auth model

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

Here is the auth model I am trying to implement :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager
# Create your models here.


class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        account = self.model(username=username)

        account.set_password(password)
        account.save()

        return account

    def create_superuser(self, username, password, **kwargs):
        account = self.create_superuser(username, password, **kwargs)
        account.is_admin = True
        account.save()

        return account


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    objects = AccountManager()
```

When I run the `createsuperuser` command from terminal, it throws this error

```
  ...................
  File "../models.py", line 22, in create_superuser
    account = self.create_superuser(username, password, **kwargs)
  File "../models.py", line 22, in create_superuser
    account = self.create_superuser(username, password, **kwargs)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Comment: infinite recursion :)
account = self.create_superuser(username, password, **kwargs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `create_superuser` method on your `AccountManager` calls itself which results in an infinite recursion, as Python has a maximum recursion depth, the infinite recursion is stopped with an exception when it is reached.

What you probably wanted to do is:

```
def create_superuser(self, username, password, **kwargs):
    account = self.create_user(username, password, **kwargs)
    account.is_admin = True
    account.save()

    return account
```